# Urban Airship : Error "Failed to associate named user with status: 403"

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, urbanairship.com

I am working on Urban Airship integration in my iOS mobile application. Push Notification is working fine , but when I try to call

```
UAirship.namedUser().identifier = name
UAirship.push().updateRegistration()
```

We are getting Error

> Failed to associate named user with status: 403

Answer (score 6):

**Solution**

Select Project in Urban Airship Dashboard ,  Go to Setting -> API & Integration -> Named Users -> Give permission to *Allow Named Users to be set from devices* .